# Adding line breaks between charts

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy 60 charts from an excel sheet to a mail.

I have a working macro but it puts some charts on the same line and adds confusion to the mail.
I would like the macro to insert Line Breaks where I want them.
I have shortened the code below because it is very long but it includes all that is needed to solve this problem.

I've tried several "solution" but most of what I find is using .body which I don't need in my macro as text will be put manually between charts and I believe it wouldn't work with the way I grab the charts.

```
Sub Mail()

Set mailApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set Mail = mailApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Mail.Display
Set wEditor = mailApp.ActiveInspector.WordEditor

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 152").Activate
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
wEditor.Application.selection.Paste

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 154").Activate
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
wEditor.Application.selection.Paste

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 6").Activate
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
wEditor.Application.selection.Paste

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 14").Activate
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
wEditor.Application.selection.Paste

*Line break here*

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 15").Activate
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
wEditor.Application.selection.Paste

End Sub
```

thanks

Comment: Have you tried `vbNewLine ` ?

Comment: vbNewLine does not work as it is not part of a text or text box.

Comment: Can you add an image of what you trying to copy and what result you expecting?

Comment: https://i.imgsafe.org/ed18c2aa93.png
In this image, Figure 1 is what I need in the mail and is what it looks like in excel. Charts C & D, E & F, G & H and I & J needs to be on the same line as they are pairs. when I execute the code above, it puts chart C,D and E on the same line and breaks the E & F pair as seen in figure 2.

Comment: Why not copy the whole thing one time?

Comment: because that would include the cells and would makes things more complicated for the person filling text between categories and makes things very bad when viewed on a cell phone.